Is $i$ definable from the complex field structure plus a predicate for the real numbers?
I know that $i$ is not definable from the complex field structure $(\mathbb{C};+,-,*,0,1)$. Rather, $i$ and $-i$ are indistinguishable. But what about the following structure: $(\mathbb{C};+,-,*,0,1,R)$, where $R$ is a unary predicate that picks out the real numbers? I believe that $i$ and $-i$ are still indistinguishable, but I don't know how to prove it.

Complex conjugation remains an automorphism of this structure.

A lot of your questions about definability have been answered by considering automorphisms. Did you try that approach for this question?
